# morris.js bar chart show hover legend (tooltip) programmatically

Tags: morris.js

I'm using morris charts alongside my table and would like to invoke tooltip on morris bar chart when a row is selected (same data is presented in the table and using graph). Is there a way to show hover legend (tooltips) programmatically, something like:

```
my_chart.showHover(row_index);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As I only need this for bar charts I added this to morris.js

```
Bar.prototype.myShowHoverLegendForRow = function(index) {
    if (this.options.hideHover !== 'always'){
        if (index < 0 || index > this.data.length - 1) {
            return null;
        }
        return (_ref = this.hover).update.apply(_ref, this.hoverContentForRow(index));
    }
}
```

Also You may need this to close(hide) legend(tooltip):

```
Bar.prototype.myHideHoverLegend = function() {
    return this.hover.hide();
}
```